# rewrite http to https for few pages

Tags: http, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I saw that there was something similar here
[How to force rewrite to HTTPS except for a few pages in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818146/how-to-force-rewrite-to-https-except-for-a-few-pages-in-apache)

So I would be very grateful if someone could help me with something opposite.
I need to rewrite **all** requests for
http://www.default.com

so I did like this:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^default.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.default.com/ [R=301,L]
```

and now I need to force the **https** protocol for some urls, like:
`http://www.default.com/user/loginUser`

etc.

and I really have no idea. I've been fighting with that for hours today and the closest I've got was some infinite loop of redirections :P

The other thing is that in subfolder where is CMS (written by some other guy) there is another .htaccess file with some rewrite rules and I don't know if this affect what I'm trying to do in any way.

I would be thankful for any advice.

Comment: Jon Lin, it doesn't work for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each url you need to do this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^user/loginUser(.*)$ https://www.default.com/user/LoginUser$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^another/url(.*)$ https://www.default.com/another/url$1 [R=301,L]
```

etc.