# How to force ssl on all pages except the admin page

Tags: apache, ssl

Let's say I have a website xxxx.com/ and I want to redirect any pages to https, except pages with /admin/, for example xxxx.com/admin/xxx.php will use http.

I tried to follow [How to force rewrite to HTTPS except for a few pages in Apache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5818146/how-to-force-rewrite-to-https-except-for-a-few-pages-in-apache)

and I came up with this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/admin\/
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/admin\/ 
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but this is not working, I typed xxxx.com/admin and it redirected to https://xxxx.com/cgi-bin/php55.cgi/admin/index.php

How do I solve this?

Comment: `/admin` is not the same as `/admin/`. Had you tried `xxxx.com/admin/` it would have worked. Make the trailing slash optional so it works on both `/admin` and `/admin/`. Change `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/admin\/` to `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/admin[\/]`.